# Conflict between autocompletion (via ctags) and the `find` command?

Tags: ctags, path

I am using Vim 8.2 on Windows 10.  Autocompletion (using `CTRL+N` or `CTRL+P`) upon creating the tags file using ctags.exe works fine for me.

Now I want to use the `find` command in vim to quickly opening any file in the project directory.  Therefore I set `set path=.,**,,` in my vimrc file; now executing `:find foo.py` opens immediately that file, which is deep inside the project.  However, trying to autocomplete freezes the editor (the status line shows `Scanning tags.`)

Is there a solution to this problem or are autocompletion and (accelerated) `find` mutually exclusive?

Comment: `:find` wasn't meant to be a fuzzy-finder. `'path'` co-operates with `gf` and friends, as well as include and define searches. `:find` and `:sfind` are basically `gf` as a command with arguments. OTOH, regular `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` will look at included files as well as tags (and other things: see `:help 'complete'`), so it's possible that so many files are included it takes a long time to process. Maybe [edit] in `:checkpath!` as well as `:setlocal complete? include? includeexpr? tags?`…

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble for this information.

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble for this information.

To summarize: configuring the `path` variable is a way to accelerate commands like `gf` rather than (or instead of) optimizing the `:find` command.   It has however a drawback: if defined too broadly, it slows down the ctags-based autocompletion like `C-n` or `C-p`.

If you wish to reword this as an answer, I would approve it - just to close the loop for other readers.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer. As I said I’d be surprised about that level of impact unless there were also lots of included files (where I am referring to `include-search`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing feedback by @D.BenKnoble: yes, setting `path` so that lots of directories/files are included does have an impact on the speed of completion commands like `C-n` and `C-p`, because the all those files are considered when searching for a completion.

A trade-off could be e.g. not to include the whole project but only those directories which matter to you.